# Eclipse how to convert automatically?

Tags: java

Say I have:

```
p.size = packetLine[0]; // where packetLine is of type String[] and element at that position is number represented by String
```

I don't want always to write

```
Integer.parseInt 

 or reverse

String.valueOf
```

Eclipse gives propositions to correct the error, can I make it to advice to convert the values?

At the moment it suggests to change the type. I would like third proposition 'Convert to Int' or 'Convert to String;

This is particularly annoying when repeating thousand times, I might just introduce my own method for converting like toInt or toString2, but in build solution would be better.

Comment: These are not casts, these are method calls.  Autocomplete would be inappropriate, because there are a number of different ways to do this (and a number of ways to deal with error conditions, etc.).

Comment: hm, that is very disappointing. Not exactly autocomplete, but rather options to do that - not necessarily the correct options in given situation, but if you know what you are doing it would be handy..

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Most dynamic languages are still strongly typed, and passing a string where a number is expected will lead to bugs. (Also, SO comments aren't the place for computer language trolling.)

Comment: @Inerdial I wasn't intending it to be "language trolling", so sorry if it came off that way. The example above is an assignment statement, any dynamic language that executed that statement wouldn't care if the right hand side returned a number or a string. It would only matter if you then tried to call some method on it that the type didn't support.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Even if it was an earnest suggestion, it'd be "fixing" the wrong problem. (Ignoring the fact that a curt "recode everything from scratch" just isn't very helpful.) The OP doesn't need to make the compiler shut up about compatible types (which strings and numbers are not), he wants to do the type coercion automatically. A type coercion you would need to do in Ruby, Python or Javascript as well as in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What you are asking for is not casting. Java uses the term casting for two operations:

   - Converting a numeric primitive to another numeric primitive by approximating the original value as much as possible e.g. `int` to `double`.
   - Storing the contents of an object reference variable to a more specific reference variable, *if and only if the referred object can actually be stored there*.
2. What you are asking for is *conversion* from String to a primitive type and vice versa. It does not usually make sense to provide shortcuts for this. There are more than one ways to do it and none is universal. E.g. a numeric String can be interpreted as an octal or a hexadecimal  number and a `float` can be converted to a String with a varying number of floating point digits, depending on the required precision...

**EDIT:**

You might be able to make your life easier with repeated operations by creating [custom editor templates in Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-editor-templates.htm). Editor templates are accessible along with the rest of the content assist proposals when you press `Control+Space`. Template creation is not always straightforward, but it can be quite helpful in some cases.

Comment: yeah finally found it. This is a whole new world to play with :-D Thanks, I am accepting.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, you're stuck with either a method on your class (toInt() like you suggested) or a static utility method. (Which is nice, if you prefer not to have lots of try/catch, you can choose to return 0 for malformed integers. Or whatever is appropriate. I like 0 instead of exception.)

The only "built-in" casting is turning anything to a String (with its toString() method), during concatenation. Like,

```
String s = "as a string, it is: " + anything; // and null becomes "null".
```

Sometimes you see this:

```
String s = "" + something; // shorthand
```

(Numeric types are implicitly cast for you, too. But mostly you're supposed to be type safe and all that.)

Answer (score 1):

You can't add implicit casts in java, as the language doesn't support it, outside of primitive types / class hierarchies.

Comment: The OP is aware of that; he/she is asking whether Eclipse can assist with these situations.